# Why is g++ failing not linking with my library? undefined reference to function

Tags: c++, batch-file, g++, mingw

When I try to compile with g++ using a library. g++ gives me an error: `undefined reference to function`. I don't know why this is happening because I am sure I am linking properly.

build batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET "build_type=O0"

SET "build_location=bin"

SET "app_name=OpenGL_Test"


REM Get a list of all the .cpp files.
SET cpp_files=
FOR /R %%f in (*.cpp) do (
    SET cpp_files=%%f
)

SET h_files=-Isrc -Iinclude/headers

SET lib_files=-Linclude/libs/libglfw3dll -lopengl32

REM Builds the files using g++
CALL g++ %cpp_files% %h_files% %lib_files% -%build_type% -o %build_location%/%build_type%/%app_name%.exe
ECHO "BUILT FILES!"

REM Starts the executable that is generated from the g++ command
ECHO "STARTING APPLICATION"
START %build_location%/%build_type%/%app_name%.exe

PAUSE
```

[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0JOA.png)

Comment: Make sure you can link without build automation, just a simple, stupid, hand-typed command line that does nothing but try to link a simple `main` against your library. If that works, advance to build automation. If not, you'll need to dive into finding what went wrong building the library.

Comment: If you echo `%cpp_files%` after the for loop I suspect you're going to find it isn't what you think it is. It's the *last* file; not all of the files. Moral: don't `@echo off` until everything *works*

Comment: There are standard tools for managing the build process. Coding your own batch files isn't the best way to do your makes. You can use either cmake or just make. I believe both run on Windows, which you appear to be using.